# How do I write this query to get back what I need?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a query that will retrieve some columns (what a surprise!). I'm horrible with anything other than simple queries and especially in Access. Below is an image of the query designer in Access.

[image]

The fields at the bottom are the fields I am looking to pull back. The project_master.ContactDesigner is the foreign key to contacts.ContactID. I want to get a list of the MilestoneNames for ID's 2, 3 and 4. Then say for example, MilestoneID 2 has a MilestoneName of Project Initiation, I want to have a record for as many projects that exists that have a start and end date in the project_milestone_dates for that MilestoneID and list the Names of the contacts for each record that are tied to the foreign key project_master.ContactDesigner. This needs to grab only the records that have a ProjectPriority of 2 for example.

Not sure if this is clear as it's very hard for me to explain what I'm looking for here but I am missing criteria or maybe even some IDs I need to add to the query? I'm so lost. The current design returns nothing in the columns.

```
SELECT milestone_def.milestonename, 
       contacts.firstname, 
       priority_def.priorityname, 
       project_milestone_dates.startdate, 
       project_milestone_dates.enddate, 
       milestone_def.milestonedefid 
FROM   (project_milestone_dates 
        INNER JOIN (priority_def 
                    INNER JOIN (contacts 
                                INNER JOIN project_master 
                                        ON ( contacts.contactid = 
                                             project_master.contactdesigner )) 
                            ON priority_def.prioritydefid = 
                               project_master.projectpriority) 
                ON project_milestone_dates.projectid = 
                   priority_def.prioritydefid) 
       INNER JOIN milestone_def 
               ON project_milestone_dates.milestoneid = 
                  milestone_def.milestonedefid 
WHERE  ( ( ( project_master.projectpriority ) = [@priority] ) 
         AND ( ( milestone_def.milestonedefid ) = 5 
                OR ( milestone_def.milestonedefid ) = 6 
                OR ( milestone_def.milestonedefid ) = 7 ) );
```

Changed it to 5 Or 6 Or 7 as that's what it should be.

Edit*

I've removed line **AND (contacts.ContactID = project_master.ContactOwner)** as I did not need that in the query.

Comment: Can you post the SQL command version of this query?  I'm rusty in my Access GUI knowledge.  The "=2 or 3 or 4" looks kinda suspect.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` only returns rows when the fields joined against are not null; otherwise it returns nothing. If you need to be able to get a row back even when a joined field is null, use `LEFT JOIN` instead. No idea whether that's the issue because I can't see your data, but it's a common pitfall for inexperienced SQL users, so I mention it nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was reading up on that thinking maybe there's a wrong join but all of the joined fields have data in them.

Comment: You used the GUI to design the query, right?  That nested `JOIN` syntax hurts my brain.

Comment: I did because Access has way too many brackets and what not for me to bother worrying where to place them all.

Comment: hat's some hideous Access syntax.
Usually when this happens, the best troubleshooting you can do is to add each table one at a time, and run the query in between.
Then you can isolate precisely which join is causing the zero return.  
Once you find it, try changing to a LEFT JOIN as Aaron suggested and examining your data.

Comment: I'm surprised your PC didn't explode.  The join between Contacts and Project Master is a bad idea; you're doing a 1-Many against the same field twice.  You might want to start with the data you need from just 2 tables, and see if you can get the results you expect.  Then add each table in, one at a time, checking your results along the way.  When queries start getting this complex, this is your best way to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that and have since removed one of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
project_milestone_dates.ProjectID = priority_def.PriorityDefID
```

That looks like a bad join.

Shouldn't it be?:

```
project_milestone_dates.ProjectID = priority_def.projectid
```

Move the project_milestone_date table so that it connects directly to project_master, and not to priority_def

Comment: I have changed it to = project_master.ProjectID. Seems to pull a blank row now rather than nothing at all though. Thanks for pointing that out, just need to look deeper now.